# Custom function fails to trigger on backgrid:exitEditMode

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backgrid

I am using backgridjs for one of my upcoming projects, I want to call a custom callback function on `backgrid:exitEditMode`, I tried something like this below

//Sample code snippet

```
var Columns = new Backgrid.Columns({
    name: "bookingID", 
    label: "ID",
    cell: "string"
});

Columns.on("backgrid:exitEditMode", function () {
    alert('test')
});
```

But the callback function fails to trigger on exiting a cell from the edit mode, am I doing something wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S : I am beginner in backbonejs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out a way of doing this

```
var grid.listenTo(collection,"backgrid:edited",function(e){alert('hi')});
```